# Como salvar dados no celular

Tags: android

Olá tenho um aplicativo que recebe determinado dado de uma api, o que deve ser feito para que o dado recebido pela api seja salvo no celular? pois quero que o aplicativo funcione sem internet

Comment: Depende do tipo de dado. Foto? Texto? Explique mais.

Comment: é um texto e um valor double

Answer (score 2):

Existem várias formas, como você recebe apenas um texto e um valor double, eu te recomendo usar SharedPreferences, que você pode implementar rapidamente e é muito mais simples que um banco de dados pra poucos dados (que seria outra opção).

Pra salvar o que você precisa, use algo assim:

```
public static final String CONSTANTE_DOUBLE = "double"; //pode ser o que vc quiser nas duas, o que importa eh usar o mesmo pra salvar e acessar
public static final String CONSTANTE_STRING = "string";

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putDouble(CONSTANTE_DOUBLE, seuDouble);
editor.putString(CONSTANTE_STRING, seuTexto);
editor.commit();
```

Note que ele funciona como um par chave-valor, entao o primeiro argumento do put é a chave, que você vai usar depois pra buscar esse valor, e o segundo é o conteúdo. Essa chave geralmente você usa uma constante estática.

E pra buscar o valor:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
double seuDouble = sharedPref.getDouble(CONSTANTE_DOUBLE, 0.0);
String seuString = sharedPref.getString(CONSTANTE_STRING, "");
```

Só passar a constante e tá pronto. O Segundo parametro quando voce lê do SharedPreferences é um valor default, caso o que você peça pro sharedPreferences não esteja lá, como forma de prevenir nullPointers.

[Documentação em Português, pra saber mais](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Acho que ficou bem claro, mas qualquer dúvida só chamar :D